# Any swap usage causes system wide freeze

Tags: 16.04, swap

Here is my system, through the prism of htop:

[image]

Lots of swap defined. It's the desktop version of Ubuntu 16.04 btw.

On this particular machine, any spilling over of memory to swap will cause a very very very long freeze, that typically also excludes the various known hacks for entering a terminal session during a freeze. Typically an infinite freeze or just longer than a sane human would wait for.

Is this very typical of 16.04? is this very atypical of 16.04?

Any straightforward troubleshoot?

Thanks!

Comment: Swap is *slooooow*.  You didn't say how much swap you started using, but with an insane 488G allocated, I would imagine you started using many GBs worth.  That will bring your system to a crawl as it will be spending all of its time waiting for data to be swapped in an out.

Comment: Actually, the freeze happens right at the first GB (or even megabytes) of swap as I recall from those cases spread over time ...